# Infrequent deadlock in MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, deadlock, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm having Aurora MySQL V2 RDS server. Following is my issue having table.

```
`CREATE TABLE `my_tbl` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `col2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `col3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `col4` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `col5` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `col6` varchar(1100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `col7` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `col8` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `col9` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `col10` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`col3`),
  KEY `col2` (`col2`),
  KEY `col4` (`col4`),
  KEY `col3_index` (`col3`,`col2`),
  KEY `idx_my_tbl_col3_col4` (`col3`,`col4`),
  KEY `idx_my_tbl_col2_col3_col4` (`col2`,`col3`,`col4`),
  KEY `idx_my_tbl_col8_col3_col4` (`col8`,`col3`,`col4`),
  KEY `idx_my_tbl_col8_col4` (`col8`,`col4`),
  KEY `col8Index` (`col8`),
  KEY `idx_my_tbl` (`col3`,`col2`,`col4`,`col10`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=154215634 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (col3)
PARTITIONS 10 */`
```

The table is partitioned into 10 based on col3. Some instances of the update queries made by my application result in deadlocks. I'm trying to update two independent rows. following is the output of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS

```
`------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2023-07-12 18:51:12 0x2b79ae229700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 36372591069, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 196, OS thread handle 47777392129792, query id 244407 10.1.0.188 admin Searching rows for update
UPDATE my_tbl USE INDEX (idx_my_tbl_col2_col3_col4) SET col4 = 1, col8 = ''2023/07/13 00:21:12'' WHERE col3 = 16681539 AND col2 = ''94790038425'' AND col4 = 0
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 297 page no 344041 n bits 0 index idx_my_tbl_col2_col3_col4 of table `mydb`.`my_tbl` /* Partition `p9` */ trx id 36372591069 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 375 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len=11; bufptr=0x2b75e7c12abf; hex= 3934373930303338343235; asc 94790038425;;
 1: len=4; bufptr=0x2b75e7c12aca; hex= 80fe8a43; asc    C;;
 2: len=4; bufptr=0x2b75e7c12ace; hex= 80000000; asc     ;;
 3: len=4; bufptr=0x2b75e7c12ad2; hex= 88be96ec; asc     ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 36372591067, ACTIVE 0 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 5 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 195, OS thread handle 47777424361216, query id 244405 10.1.0.143 admin updating
UPDATE my_tbl USE INDEX (idx_my_tbl_col2_col3_col4) SET col4 = 1, col8 = ''2023/07/13 00:21:12'' WHERE col3 = 16681529 AND col2 = ''94790038425'' AND col4 = 0
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 297 page no 344041 n bits 0 index idx_my_tbl_col2_col3_col4 of table `mydb`.`my_tbl` /* Partition `p9` */ trx id 36372591067 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 374 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len=11; bufptr=0x2b75e7c12aa2; hex= 3934373930303338343235; asc 94790038425;;
 1: len=4; bufptr=0x2b75e7c12aad; hex= 80fe8a39; asc    9;;
 2: len=4; bufptr=0x2b75e7c12ab1; hex= 80000000; asc     ;;
 3: len=4; bufptr=0x2b75e7c12ab5; hex= 88bc168c; asc     ;;

[bitmap of 256 bytes in hex: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ]
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 297 page no 344041 n bits 0 index idx_my_tbl_col2_col3_col4 of table `mydb`.`my_tbl` /* Partition `p9` */ trx id 36372591067 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 375 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len=11; bufptr=0x2b75e7c12abf; hex= 3934373930303338343235; asc 94790038425;;
 1: len=4; bufptr=0x2b75e7c12aca; hex= 80fe8a43; asc    C;;
 2: len=4; bufptr=0x2b75e7c12ace; hex= 80000000; asc     ;;
 3: len=4; bufptr=0x2b75e7c12ad2; hex= 88be96ec; asc     ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
------------`
```

I want to understand why this deadlock is occurring?

Comment: what is your `isolation level`? Output for `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tx_isolation'`
Regardless, I think this is an issue of Gap Lock. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72173253/locking-issue-in-delete-query-mysql-5-7-18/72351255#72351255)

Comment: @Asgar isolation level is 'REPEATABLE-READ'

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned the log.
Let me try and explain

You have transaction 1:

```
UPDATE my_tbl USE INDEX (idx_my_tbl_col2_col3_col4) 
SET col4 = 1, col8 = ''2023/07/13 00:21:12'' 
WHERE col3 = 16681539 AND col2 = ''94790038425'' AND col4 = 0

This query is trying to update with following conditions:
col3=16681539
col2=94790038425
col4=0
```

Similarly, you have your second transaction:

```
UPDATE my_tbl USE INDEX (idx_my_tbl_col2_col3_col4) 
SET col4 = 1, col8 = ''2023/07/13 00:21:12'' 
WHERE col3 = 16681529 AND col2 = ''94790038425'' AND col4 = 0;

This query is trying to update with the following conditions:
col3=16681529
col2=94790038425
col4=0
```

The gap lock exists because Transaction 2 is waiting for Transaction 1
that could satisfy these conditions.
I hope you have read the link I mentioned in the comment sections.
The summary is MySQL locks row that could have been there.